# Puppet "require" not working as expected

Tags: java, maven, puppet

I have the following two manifests:

```
class profile::maven inherits profile::base {
  # Hiera
  $version = hiera('profile::maven::version', '3.2.1')
  $settings = hiera_hash('profile::maven::settings', undef)
  $environments = hiera_hash('profile::maven::environments', undef)

  # Dependencies
  require '::profile::java'

  # Modules
  class { '::maven::maven':
    version => $version,
  }

  if ($settings) {
    create_resources('::maven::settings', $settings)
  }

  if ($environments) {
    create_resources('::maven::environments', $environments)
  }
}
```

and

```
class profile::java inherits profile::base {
  # Hiera
  $distribution = hiera('profile::java::distribution', 'jdk')
  $version = hiera('profile::java::version', 'present')

  # Modules
  class { '::java':
    distribution => $distribution,
    version      => $version,
  }

  # Parameters
  $java_home = $::java::java_home

  file { 'profile-script:java.sh':
    ensure  => present,
    path    => '/etc/profile.d/java.sh',
    content => template('profile/java.sh.erb'),
  }
```

}

I want that `profile::java` has completely finished before `profile::maven` is executed.

The `site.pp`looks as follows and should not be modified in order to comply with puppet's role-profile approach later (work in progress):

```
node 'gamma.localdomain' {
  include 'profile::java'
  include 'profile::maven'
}
```

After compilation the scripts starts with downloading the maven archive. Why does

```
require '::profile::java'
```

not ensure the execution order? Has someone an idea how to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem here is that the `require profile::java` is scoped to the `profile::maven` class, so all **resources** declared in the latter class depend on `profile::java`. However, this will not propagate to classes that `profile::maven` declares, such as `maven::maven`.

To achieve that, you can establish a dependency among those classes

```
include profile::java
include maven::maven

Class[profile::java] -> Class[maven::maven]
```

This can incur substantial complexity in the dependency graph, so be wary of that. This can be avoided using the [Anchor Pattern](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Anchor_Pattern).

Note that use of the require function is [discouraged due to possible dependency cycle issues](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/function.html#require).

Answer (score 1):

Since at least Puppet 3.5 you can use "[contain](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.4/reference/lang_containment.html)" to ensure that everything inside profile::java completes before profile::maven.  The following addition to profile::java would be required:

```
class profile::java inherits profile::base {
  ...
  contain '::maven::maven'
  ...
}
```

Answering this old, answered question as it comes up first when googling "puppet require does not work"