# Function contain() vs. Anchor Pattern in Puppet

Tags: puppet

This post refers to [Puppet "require" not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433335/puppet-require-not-working-as-expected).

Is it possible to replace the Anchor Pattern with the function `contain` maintaining execution order and hinder declared classes of floating out. The two manifests look as follows:

```
class profile::maven inherits profile::base {
  # Hiera
  $version = hiera('profile::maven::version', '3.2.1')
  $settings = hiera_hash('profile::maven::settings', undef)
  $environments = hiera_hash('profile::maven::environments', undef)

  include 'profile::java'

  anchor { 'profile::maven::begin': }

  class { '::maven::maven': version => $version, }

  anchor { 'profile::maven::end': }

  if ($settings) {
    create_resources('::maven::settings', $settings)
  }

  if ($environments) {
    create_resources('::maven::environment', $environments)
  }

  Anchor['profile::maven::begin'] -> Class['profile::java'] -> Class['::maven::maven'] -> Anchor['profile::maven::end']

}
```

and

```
class profile::java inherits profile::base {
  # Hiera
  $distribution = hiera('profile::java::distribution', 'jdk')
  $version = hiera('profile::java::version', 'present')

  anchor { 'profile::java::begin': }

  class { '::java':
    distribution => $distribution,
    version      => $version,
  }

  anchor { 'profile::java::end': }

  # Parameters
  $java_home = $::java::java_home

  file { 'profile-script:java.sh':
    ensure  => present,
    path    => '/etc/profile.d/java.sh',
    content => template('profile/java.sh.erb'),
  }

  Anchor['profile::java::begin'] -> Class['::java'] -> File['profile-script:java.sh'] -> Anchor['profile::java::end']

}
```

Because of the current issue [PUP-1597](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1597) in Puppet 3.6.x, the profile classes have to be renamed, otherwise we get `Error: undefined method 'ref' for nil:NilClass`. Applying the changes result in:

```
class profile::mavenp inherits profile::base {
  # Hiera
  $version = hiera('profile::maven::version', '3.2.1')
  $settings = hiera_hash('profile::maven::settings', undef)
  $environments = hiera_hash('profile::maven::environments', undef)

  include 'profile::javap'

  class { '::maven::maven': version => $version, }
  contain 'maven::maven'

  if ($settings) {
    create_resources('::maven::settings', $settings)
  }

  if ($environments) {
    create_resources('::maven::environment', $environments)
  }

  Class['profile::javap'] -> Class['::maven::maven']

}
```

and

```
class profile::javap inherits profile::base {
  # Hiera
  $distribution = hiera('profile::java::distribution', 'jdk')
  $version = hiera('profile::java::version', 'present')

  class { '::java':
    distribution => $distribution,
    version      => $version,
  }
  contain 'java'

  # Parameters
  $java_home = $::java::java_home

  file { 'profile-script:java.sh':
    ensure  => present,
    path    => '/etc/profile.d/java.sh',
    content => template('profile/java.sh.erb'),
  }

}
```

Are these changes equivalent?

If someone has a better idea of how to the deal with technologcial dependencies in Puppet using the profile/role approach, do not hesitate to share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The latter pair of classes are not completely equivalent equivalent to the former.  The biggest issue is in `profile::javap`.  Note that its analog `profile::java` has this as part of its dependency chain:

```
Class['::java'] -> File['profile-script:java.sh']
```

Class `profile::javap` has no analog of that.

I'm not 100% certain whether class `profile::mavenp` is equivalent to class `profile::maven`, though I think it is.  Your intent would be clearer and my uncertainty would be resolved if the former included

```
contain 'profile::javap'
```

instead of (or in addition to)

```
include 'profile::javap'
```